# Why isn't my public class and it's public methods visible in my other class?

Tags: c#, class, xamarin

I have two files that look like this:

```
public class ShowItem
{
    public string name;
    public string date;

    public ShowItem(string name, string date)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ShowAdapter<ShowItem> : BaseAdapter<ShowItem>
{
    List<ShowItem> shows = new List<ShowItem>();

    ...

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ...

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = shows[position] ... ;
        return view;
    }
}
```

However in the second class, when I try to access the `ShowItem` methods after accessing the "shows" list like this: `shows[position]` (which is accessing a list of `ShowItems`, so it should be a `ShowItem` too), the class is identified as an `Object` class and I can only access the methods that are there (Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString), but not the public methods or variables in the `ShowItem` class. I've tried casting it, but it is also just identifed as an Object class even when I cast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ShowAdapter<>` class is generic with generic type name `ShowItem`.  It's hiding the actual class `ShowItem`.  It probably shouldn't be generic.

```
public class ShowAdapter : BaseAdapter<ShowItem>
{
    ...
}
```